# Magento setBeforeAuthUrl to redirect user works in firefox but not Chrome

Tags: php, magento, redirect, magento-1.9

I want to redirect the customer to one of two urls based on a condition after he logs in.

If the user has his profile complete (set by all_set field), we redirect him to the My Feed url, otherwise we redirect him to the Account Edit Page

```
class Ip_Redirection_Model_Observer_Customer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    /*method for Login Redirection*/
   public function customerLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {    

      $customerUser = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
      $customerData = $customerUser->getData();


      //print_r($_SESSION['customer']); exit();
      if($customerData['is_allset'] == 1){
         $_session = $this->_getSession();

          $_session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('redirection')->setRedirectOnIsAllSet());
         } else {

          $_session = $this->_getSession();
          $_session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('redirection')->setRedirectOnLogin());
         }

   }

   ...
 }
```

Now this works perfectly in firefox i.e the user is redirected to the correct url. 
The **redirection** also happens in **chrome**, but the **user doesn't get logged in.**

The session is not found. When however, the page is refreshed, the user appears logged in and all works fine.

Comment: Are you testing on localhost ?